# Load opentype font into java.awt

Tags: java, awt, opentype

How do I load an opentype font into awt? Using `createFont` with `Font.TRUETYPE_FONT` gives me `[error] java.io.IOException ( java.io.IOException: Can't read font.otf )`

Sample code (jython):

```
Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, File("font.otf"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like java.awt.Font does not support OpenType, nor TYPE2.
See, http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6992611.

So you could either use a .ttf along with `java.awt.Font` class, or use another class such as `com.itextpdf.text.Font` to work with .otf